# How to update a text view from a Room database using LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I'm trying to create a simple counter app that uses Databinding, Room database, and live data. Currently when the user presses the plus button, it updates a local live data value which then updates the database number. When I try to attach the value from the database dbCount, I get an databinding error. How can I get the live data from the database to the text view?

Note: I'm new to android development so  I'm still learning the concepts.
[Project Repository](https://github.com/edgarjc/TrackMySleepQualityCoroutines)

fragment_number.xml

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/dbView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{sleepTrackerViewModel.dbCount}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/display"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/display"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/display" />
```

DatabaseDAO

```
   //Selects first entry
    @Query("SELECT number from daily_sleep_quality_table WHERE nightId = 1")
    fun getFirst(): LiveData<Int>
```

NumberViewModel

```
    private val dbCount = database.getFirst()

//Holds the count
    private val _count = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val count: LiveData<Int>
        get() = _count


       fun plus(){
        uiScope.launch{
            //adds to current count
            _count.value = (_count.value)?.plus(1)

            //Gets entry with ID 1 and updates number
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val currentNum = database.get(1) ?: return@withContext

                currentNum.number = _count.value!!

                database.update(currentNum )
            }


            number.value = getTonightFromDatabase()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your view just call the NumberViewModel count like this

```
private lateinit var viewModel: NumberViewModel
```

if you using fragment put the function on `onActivityCreated` if you using activity put it `onCreate`

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NumberViewModel::class.java)
viewmodel.count.observe(this,Observe{count->
     dbView.text = count
})
```

It's very easy if you apply the **KOIN** for binding ViewModel and your DB here the reference about [KOIN](https://insert-koin.io/)

Comment: Thanks!! I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours.